# How to display a BIM 360 model with forge?

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-bim360

I have been following along with the data visualisation API example found here
https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/dataviz/v1/developers_guide/introduction/overview/

And have gotten to the point where I can get it to work with the default model.
I'd like to be able to get this to work by taking a model from BIM 360, however the example way to do this that's been given names files and folders that aren't included in the example project.

Following along with the example and creating the missing files results in the application loading, but not bringing in a model, which I believe is because the application failed to log in to BIM 360, but no login prompt appeared.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The tutorial section related to what you're trying to do (https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/dataviz/v1/developers_guide/advanced_topics/integrate_bim360/) is a work-in-progress. I've reported this issue to the engineering team.

In the meantime, if you'd like to try loading an existing model from BIM360 Docs into the reference application, the easiest (albeit hacky) way would be to "steal" the 3-legged access token and the model URN directly from BIM360 Docs. Basically, open one of your designs in BIM360 Docs, open your browser's DevTools, go to the Network tab, and search for requests to one of the Forge endpoints (for example, requests with `derivativeservice` in their URL):

[image]

You can then get the access token and URN from there, and hard-code them in the reference app.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know, I'll give this a try and see how it goes!

Comment: Any news with documentation? I implemented Fusion 360 tutorial, which was really painful since I tried to use modern React with hooks and everything, but I have no idea how to utilize that to access BIM 360 uploaded models.

Comment: The original dataviz sample application has been reworked to be simpler and easier to reuse: https://github.com/autodesk-platform-services/aps-iot-extensions-demo. You can configure it with env. variables to load whatever design your application client ID and secret has access to.

Answer (score 1):

Did you already try this tutorials ? [Learn Forge Tutorials](https://learnforge.autodesk.io/#/?id=what39s-in-this-tutorial)

You will find on this website some guides to create a Forge app working with **buckets/objects** but also access **BIM360** or **Fusion360** models.
Different languages are available for each tutorial so you will be able to achieve what you want !